# How to add notification alert in perforce if someone check in the code into repository?

Tags: javascript, hibernate-mapping, repository-pattern, perforce-client-spec

The p4 reviews command, which is used by the Perforce change review daemon, uses the values in the Reviews: field; when activated, it will send email to users whenever files they've subscribed to in the Reviews: field have changed. Files listed in this field must be specified in depot syntax; for example, if user Joe has a Reviews: field value of

So, my question is: how to add notification alert in perforce , if some one check in the code into repository

Answer (score 0):

open "p4 users"
add below line
Reviews: `//client spec...`

save it.